# File uploaded WITHOUT its content to web service using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, web, restful-url

I am uploading file using jquery ajax but the problem is file is uploaded without its content. FIle uploaded with 0Kb. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploading() {
var u = document.getElementById('uploadbr');
alert(u.value);

                    $.ajax({ 
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://10.20.1.93:8080/Service1/UploadFile?fileName="+u.value, 

                        success: function( data ) 
                        { 
                            alert( data ); 
                        } 
                    });    
                } 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="uploadform" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadbr" type="file" name="upfile" size="40" /><br/>
<input type="button" name="upbutton" value="Upload" onclick="uploading()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code on server side.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFile?fileName={fileName}")]
        public string UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
        {
            //save file
            try
            {
                string absFileName = string.Format("{0}\\FileUpload\\{1}"
                                        , AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                                        , fileName);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(absFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fileContents.CopyTo(fs);
                    fileContents.Close();
                }
                return "Upload OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "FAIL ==> " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Now tell me what can i do? where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem SOLVED!!! But thanks for replying. My script was wrong. Here is the correct one.

```
function uploading(){
    var fileIn = $("#uploadbr")[0];
    //Has any file been selected yet?
    if (fileIn.files === undefined || fileIn.files.length == 0) {
        alert("Please select a file");
        return;
    }

    //We will upload only one file in this demo
    var file = fileIn.files[0];
    //Show the progress bar
    $("#progressbar").show();
var u = document.getElementById('uploadbr');
alert(u.value);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://10.20.1.93:8080/Service1/UploadFile?fileName="+u.value,
        type: "POST",
        data: file,
        processData: false, //Work around #1
        contentType: file.type, //Work around #2
        success: function(){
            $("#progressbar").hide();
        },
        error: function(){alert("Failed");},
        //Work around #3
        xhr: function() {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',showProgress, false);
            } else {
                console.log("Upload progress is not supported.");
            }
            return myXhr;
        }
    });
}
```

from this i can upload almost any file with max size 64kb.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files using XMLHttpRequest(AJAX).
You can use this plugin instead [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload)
Moreover, With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. E.g. through [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old browsers.
[Refrence1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) 
[Refrence2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: I did not use XMLHttpRequest(AJAX). And file is being uploaded but without its content.

Comment: Using [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) can ease your code. And can you be more specific on **file is being uploaded nut without its content**

Comment: when i select a text file to upload, it is uploaded but not its content. Means i have some information save in a text.txt which has some size on disk but when i upload that file, it is uploaded as empty file and its size on disk becomes 0kb.